# Compile c program with access to stdlib functions, but without _start and all of the libc init functions using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, std, libc

So essentially I want to compile a c program statically with gcc, and I want it to be able to link c stdlib functions, but I want it to start at main, and not include the `_start` function as well as the libc init stuff that happens before main. Normally when you want to compile a program without `_start`, you run gcc with the `-nostdlib` flag, but I want to also be able to include code from stdlib, just not the libc init. Is there any way to do this?

I know that this could cause a lot of problems, but for my use case I'm not actually running the c program itself so it makes sense to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to link (and probably call/execute) stdlib code while sabotaging its preconditions and "assumptions"? Sure? We might be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Did you try to add appropriate linker options as `-lc`? As with any other library, only unresolved references will pull modules from it.

Comment: @Yunnosch there might be perfectly legit reasons to not use the startup files of libc and still want to use a few libc functions. For exemple if you want to use libm (maths library) it requires a few symbols of libc. it works perfectly fine to link with -nostdlib -lm -lc

Comment: So there is a subset of stdlib which can be used without executing the startups? OK.

Comment: For background, I am trying to write a program that can create shellcode from arbitrary c code. Shellcode is hijacking the memory space of another process, so it doesn't need to do libc initialization itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option  `-nostdlib` tells the linker to not use the startup files (ie. the code that is executed before the `main`).

> ```
> -nostdlib
>
> Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. 
> No startup files and only the libraries you specify are
> passed to the linker, and options specifying linkage of the system
> libraries, such as -static-libgcc or -shared-libgcc, are ignored.
>
> The compiler may generate calls to memcmp, memset, memcpy and memmove. 
> These entries are usually resolved by entries in libc. These
> entry points should be supplied through some other mechanism when this
> option is specified.
> ```

It is frequent to use this option in low-level bare-metal programming in order to control exactly what is going on.

You can still use the functions of your libc by using `-lc`. However keep in mind that some of the libc function depend on the startup code. For example in some implementations `printf` requires dynamic memory allocation and the heap is initialized by the startup code.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks thats what I was looking for, I think `-nostdlib -lc` will accomplish my task